# Prestashop 1.6 - Syntax error when adding Facebook Pixel to the HEAD section

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6, facebook-pixel

`PrestaShop v1.6.1.10`

I have a problem adding Facebook pixel code to my PS header. Adding the pixel causes a fatal error. There is a syntax problem... it looks like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "/shop/themes/default-bootstrap/header.tpl" on line 86 "{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?" - Unexpected ".", expected one of: "","" , ")" <-- thrown in /shop/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 86
```

I tried disabling HTLM minifer, clearing the cache, etc. Nothing helps. I think the code compiler can't understand this new Facebook pixel syntax or something. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting "pure" HTML / Javascript inside a Prestashop smarty (.TPL) file, you'll need to wrap your code between

```
{literal} your code here {/literal}
```

tags.

Keep in mind that this is not the "Prestashop way" to achieve your task, you should consider [build a simple module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/) to insert your code through a front display hook.

Comment: OK, it works good now. Tahnk U.